# Facebook Native Ads in Custom Table Cells

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to integrate Facebook Native Ads in my app using that guide:
https://friendlyublog.com/implementing-native-facebook-ads-for-ios-apps-9dc4174ae1a3

The ads load just fine and I can display them in my TableView, but it seems I can't make them tappable despite using registerView as documented in the SDK.

Did any of you meet the same issue? Any idea what could make registerView not work? Something is obviously messing with tap events but I just can't figure out what's going on...

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: i am also facing same issue, you got any solution?